# Homophone Riddle 7

Tags: riddle, word

This one can't be hard.

> These homophones deal with money
>   I can have a person on me
>   Or I could have a flower
>   When they get to one hundred they use paper

What are the homophones?

Hint:

> Think about coins, not value

Comment: Been waiting for this. (+1) :D

Comment: Having trouble making a hint...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re talking about

> PENNY and PENNI.

These homophones deal with money

> A Penny is one cent, equal to one hundredth of a dollar. A Penni is a Finnish currency unit, equal to one hundredth of a markka.

I can have a person on me

> Could be Queen Elizabeth II, at least for the old Canadian pennies.

Or I could have a flower

> A Finnish penni can have a flower on it.

When they get to one hundred they use paper

> One hundred pennies is a paper US dollar. One hundred pennis is a paper Finnish markka.

Comment: Yay! This is it! :) +1

Answer (score 11):

These homophones deal with money

> Could they be scent and cent? Maybe also bill and Bill or Ben and Ben? (I'm not sure how many to find.)

I can have a person on me

> A cent or a bill can have a person on you, a Ben (Franklin) is a US one hundred.

Or I could have a flower

> Flowers have scents

They both come from one hundred

> Cent is French for one hundred, and a Ben is a US one hundred.

Comment: You're on the scent but not quite! :) +1

Comment: flowers have scents, but scents don't have a flower :P

Comment: @Duck - is it just the reasoning that is wrong? or are the homophones wrong

Comment: Probably doesn't count, and is in the wrong direction, but there is the U.S. wheat penny, which has at one point featured two ears of wheat that are post flowering stage.

Comment: The homophones are wrong, but @asandwhich is so close if you don't go on with the wheat

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it's

> penny and peony

which are

> a coin(which can have people on it, and when you have 100 pennies it is equivalent to a dollar bill) and a flower respectively

Comment: Penny is right, but peony isn't. Nice job, though and have fun puzzling +1

Comment: @Duck Woohoo, I can finally put my bots into action :)

Answer (score 2):

These homophones deal with money

> saint and cent
> (saint helenian pounds(shp) is a currency)

I can have a person on me or I could have a flower

> the cents have person or flower engraved on them
> (for example canadian cent has flower on one side and person on other side)

When they get to one hundred they use paper

> 100 cent = 1 dollar paper note

Comment: Sorry, but nope :) +1

Answer (score 2):

fun answer - Is it..

> Me? (Cashbee)

These homophones deal with money

> **Cash**bee

I can have a person on me

> I love giving piggyback rides

Or I could have a flower

> As a bee, I love flowers

When they get to one hundred they use paper

> I can't count over a hundred in my head. I need to write the numbers down from that point on.

Comment: If fun answer like this one are not welcome, please let me know and I will stop posting them (as long as I'm certain that they're incorrect like this one)

Comment: They are very much welcome but for this one maybe you could have said it in the comments but this is not a homophone pair :) +1

Comment: Also, how would I know that you like to give piggy-back rides?